# Select div after parent with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="col-1-3">
    <div class="click"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-1-3">
</div>
<div class="col-1-2">
</div>
```

Using jQuery, I need to select the col-1-2 div when a user clicks on the "click" div. I need to replace col-1-2 with col-1-3. So far, I have tried a variety of methods using parent();, next();, find(); etc. etc. Right now, I looking into:

```
$(".click").parent().next(".col-1-2").removeClass("col-1-2").addClass("col-1-3");
```

That obviously doesn't work but I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: If you want an element for the user to click on to trigger some JavaScript: Use a button, it is what they are designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next` will only look at the immediate next element. You need to use [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to test all the following siblings.

Using `this` instead of a selector will make sure that you are dealing with the div that was actually clicked rather than another one with the same class name.

```
$(this).parent().nextAll(".col-1-2").removeClass("col-1-2").addClass("col-1-3");
```

You may also wish to filter the results to apply the change to only [the *first* match](http://api.jquery.com/first/).

Comment: it also work if you use `siblings(".col-1-2")` instead of `nextAll()`

Comment: @YerkoPalma — Providing that it wouldn't be a problem to get *previous* siblings as well as later ones.

Comment: nextAll does work, but I need to only change the closest col-1-2. If I have another div class named col-1-2 it looks like both change, hence the nextAll.

Comment: @user715564 — See the last paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One more slightly shorter version:

```
$(this).parent().siblings(".col-1-2").toggleClass("col-1-2 col-1-3");
```

[`$.fn.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) can be used instead or combination of `removeClass` + `addClass`: `col-1-2` will be removed and `col-1-3` will be added.